# Chrome JS console, how to run in the background?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, google-chrome-console

Hi I'm trying to run a loop in Google Chrome JS console. But the script seems to pause/freeze whenever I minimize or move to another window.

How can I make it so it runs in the background until I manually stop it?

This is a general problem with every loop script I try in Chrome.

Comment: It depends on what your script does. Some/many sites pause themselves when they're not focused.

Answer (score 3):

This is caused by unused tabs being frozen to save memory, resources and battery (a feature [originally](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/09/tab-discarding) released in Chrome 46).

You can disable it for any given tab or domain, by navigating to `chrome://discards`, then toggling `Auto Discardable` for your desired tab.

There's also [DoNotDiscard](https://github.com/WorldLanguages/DoNotDiscard) is a simple extension that prevents Chrome from suspending all tabs.